# Best Fabric scripts for Django

Tags: django, deployment, fabric

What are the best stock Fabric scripts for deploying a typical Django project? Fabric looks very good, but seems to require you to start from scratch and write your own deployment script.  Coming from Capistrano, I'd like to start with something that works more out-of-the-box that others have tested rather than writing one from scratch.

Ideally I'd like one that syncs the database, performs migrations using South, backs up the site and database, and can roll back previous deploys.

Answer (score 26):

Since everyone's environment is different, most Fabric scripts are going to be different from each other. So a "stock" Fabric script for anything will likely never exist.

Fabric allows you to easily create your own. A couple links I found useful are:

- [Fabric, Django, Git, Apache, mod_wsgi, virtualenv and pip deployment](http://morethanseven.net/2009/07/27/fabric-django-git-apache-mod-wsgi-virtualenv-and-p/)
- [Deploying Django with Fabric](http://lethain.com/deploying-django-with-fabric/)

Comment: If you ask how to deploy you often get the answer "use fabric". For me this answer is not much better than "use ssh". Every deployment is different, since everybody does it on its own. It is sad that the python community has no default way up to now. But I am an optimist. I guess there will be a deploy tool which suits all use cases since it is extensible.

Comment: The question is essentially looking for a "best practices" packaged solution - or in more buzzwordy terms "an opinionated framework" that solves some common use case.

"Fabric", "use bash", "write in C" are the typical non-answers to the question.

Answer (score 9):

Check this tutorial

I have found on this a good howto for work on django projects

http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/02/09/starting-a-django-project-the-right-way/

Comment: Author here. Glad you (both) found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at [Woven](http://packages.python.org/woven/main.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no longer maintained.

Comment: Last update from original github repo is from 2011. Some forks exists, but none seem to be very active.