# How to run a series of manage.py commands in Django?

Tags: django

I have a Django project. Everytime I deploy, I need to run a series of manage.py command (such as syncdb, south migiration, fixture update).

I am getting tired of type the command line by line and therefore I wrote a python script to do these:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'manage.py', 'syncdb'])
#Skip the detail
subprocess.call(['python', 'manage.py', 'loaddata', 'setup/fixture.xml'])
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `fabric`, a Python library that allows you to script remote actions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374921/best-fabric-scripts-for-django) has some links in the accepted answer for more information on `fabric` and django.

You can also [call management commands directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/django-admin/#running-management-commands-from-your-code):

```
from django.core.management import call_command

call_command('syncdb')
call_command('loaddata', 'setup/fixture.xml')
```

Save that as a normal python file and execute it from your shell or as part of your deployment scripts.