# Migration of Codebase Locally to Production - Django

Tags: python, django, deployment, centos

I have developed a few smaller applications locally and have yet to deploy them.

I am running `django 1.5/python 2.7 with git`.

I'm using `south` for database migration.

I'm wondering what are my options to automatically sync a given django app (say there is more than 1) within a django project with a remote server (a vps running `centos`) ?

I'm basically looking to work on one app, out of (2) django apps and only deploy one right now to a production (remote) server running the same setup as local (just without the default local dev server and `using gunicorn/nginx`)

`South` has made migrations so easy, is there something as simple for deployment?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried fabric? See E.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374921/best-fabric-scripts-for-django)

Comment: Another thought - does git have to be setup on both environments beforehand? How do I get the same initial committed code on both local/prod?